# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219 in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have used illuminate/html in laravel to create a form and insert data to it.
this is my routes.php:

```
Route::post('/userlog', 'LogController@userlog');
```

this is my view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
    {!! Form::open(['url' => '/userlog']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('phone', 'User phone:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('phone', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

and this is the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\Requests;

class LogController extends Controller
{
    public function userlog(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request::all();
        print_r($input);die();
    }

}
```

I face this error:
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:

What is the problem?

Comment: What URL is the form actually `POST`ing to when you double check this?

Comment: Press `F12` and go to `Network` tab and see which URL the form is being posted to.

Comment: @Muhammet It is posted to 'userlog'

Comment: Make sure the form method is `POST`, `userlog` should be relative to the base url, try 
`{!! Form::open(['action' => 'LogController@userlog', 'method'=>'POST']) !!}`

Comment: @Muhammet I tested your code but it does not work and I get the same error.

Comment: You could try `php artisan route:clear` from command line and if that doesn't work post the result of `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: @Muhammet I checked two commands and I see this result=>could not open input file:artisan

Comment: Go to your laravel project folder first & execute the command from there.

Comment: This is the result of both commands:[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()

Comment: Your form helper package is not compatible with your version of laravel. You have to get the newer version of the package.

Comment: @Muhammet How can I do so? I ran composer require illuminate/html --profile to add the package

Comment: Let's continue in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104020/temp

Comment: @Muhammet I cant chat there since I dont have 20 reputation :(

Comment: Then run `composer remove illuminate/html` and `composer require laravelcollective/html`

Comment: I ran commands but I dont know what to do now.I receive the same error.

Comment: See the installation guide https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

Comment: I installed successfully but I still recieve the error :( it is my copmoser artisan route:list result=>       | POST     | userlog |      | App\Http\Controllers\LogController@userlog

Comment: Then somehow you are not posting the form data to the correct URL.